# How to send in "NULL/DbNull" into a table-column with the datatype: nullable int

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, null

I got a table in sql-server 2012 with a column that is the datatype int but also nullable.

I've a textbox that when left empty should insert `NULL` into the nullable int cell. But I'm having trouble with what type to send in to be translated as `null`. What I want is a datatype of int but also null (int?) to send into the database.

```
var tbl_row = db.table.Where(n => n.key.Equals(key)).SingleOrDefault();

tbl_row.nullable_int = this.tb.Text == "" ? [null int value] : int.Parse(this.tb.Text);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should write:

```
tbl_row.nullable_int = this.tb.Text == "" ? (int?)null : int.Parse(this.tb.Text);
```

for the conditional operator expression to be valid.

According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

> Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.

In your case, `null` and an expression evaluated as an `int` confused the compiler. By explicitly casting the first expression to `int?`, there is now a way for it to figure out how to evaluate the conditional expression.

Comment: May I suggest the use of `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.tb.Text)` instead of `this.tb.Text == ""`

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Oh, OK then. Thank you very much @GrantWinney for the warning. But still " " will pass the condition test but fail `int.Parse()` and will throw Exception.

Comment: Just make sure that tbl_row.nullable_int property is indeed of type Nullable<int>

Comment: Nevermind my earlier comment. This works, I was trying to cast int? on a not nullable column.

Comment: @mcl That's not enough. The compiler would still complain about the conditional operator having two outcomes with confusing types.

Comment: @PresidentCamacho Glad it worked. I just tested it myself: http://ideone.com/1iQbsk

Comment: tbl_row.nullable_int = this.tb.Text == "" ? (int?)null : (int?)int.Parse(this.tb.Text);

Comment: @mcl I didn't need (int?) in (int?)int.Parse(this.tb.Text)

Comment: @mcl Yes. The `(int?)` casts are still required, even though the property `tbl_row.nullable_int` is of the right type.

Comment: I guess the compiler can now safely infer that when the columns is of a correct type

Comment: It doesn't. It would never accept `tbl_row.nullable_int = this.tb.Text == "" ? null : int.Parse(this.tb.Text);`, regardless of the type of the property

Answer (score 0):

There is a singleton instance of a DBNull class. Try assingning `DBNull.Value`

Comment: Already tried that: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.DBNull' and 'int'.

Comment: tbl_row.nullable_int = this.tb.Text == "" ? (object)DBNull.Value : (object)int.Parse(this.tb.Text); The ? operator requires both of its returning arguments to be of the same type or to be implicitly convertible.

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: never mind see w0lf's answer, I didn't see that you're using EF